# Share secondary cache accross different applications

Tags: caching, coldfusion, ehcache, coldfusion-9

We are using a CMS with secondary cache enabled:

**Application.cfc**

```
<cfset THIS.ormsettings.secondarycacheenabled = true />
<cfset THIS.ormsettings.cacheprovider = "ehcache" />
<cfset THIS.ormsettings.cacheConfig="ehcache.xml" />
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
    <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="true"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
        diskPersistent="true"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        />
</ehcache>
```

The entities are set to `cacheuse="transactional"` like so `<cfcomponent persistent="true" entityname="news" table="mews" cacheuse="transactional">`

Saving an article in the CMS works great and it instantly reflects changes after saving.

One of the sites which is managed by this CMS should share the cache with the CMS. Otherwise the application reflects the changes only after timeout value set in the site's `ehcache.xml`:

```
<ehcache>
    <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>
    <defaultCache
        maxElementsInMemory="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="1800"
        timeToLiveSeconds="1800"
        overflowToDisk="true"
        maxElementsOnDisk="10000000"
        diskPersistent="true"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        />
</ehcache>
```

Is it possible to share the cache between two different applications? Would it be possible to configure this in the two `Application.cfc`'s?